# sed solution to extract the gecos from /etc/passwd based on the username

Tags: text-processing, sed, aix

I need a sed solution for the work I am doing. I need to extract the name from `/etc/passwd` file based on the AIX user id (username). So far I have this and it isn't working. Any working solution would be appreciated.

```
sed "/^Ravi02/s/\(^.\{21\}\).\([a-zA-Z]\{50\}\)/\1/p" /export/home/Ravi02/passwd
```

Here are some example entries from the passwd file:

```
Jose01:!:49030:49082:Freeman, Joseph III:/export/home/p1jxf01:/bin/ksh
Ravi02:!:37242:1580:Dronavalli, Ravi:/export/home/j1rxd02:/bin/ksh
Beny01:!:49335:49040:Young, Ben:/export/home/p1bmy01:/bin/ksh
```

Based on the id I need to extract the name. 
If the id is "Jose01" I should get "Freeman, Joseph III"
or if it the id is "Ravi02" then I should get "Dronavalli, Ravi".

Comment: Does the solution have to be `sed`?  Would `awk` or other tools also be acceptable?

Comment: Or on AIX have you considered using `lsuser` instead?

Comment: Here is some example entries from the passwd file.

Comment: Jose01:!:49030:49082:Freeman, Joseph III:/export/home/p1jxf01:/bin/ksh
Ravi02:!:37242:1580:Dronavalli, Ravi:/export/home/j1rxd02:/bin/ksh
Beny01:!:49335:49040:Young, Ben:/export/home/p1bmy01:/bin/ksh

Comment: Based on the id I need to extract the name. If the id is "Jose01" I should get "Freeman, Joseph III" or if it the id is "Ravi02" then I should get "Dronavalli Ravi"

Comment: I think you're better off with `grep "^Ravi02:" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5`.

Comment: I know you said /etc/passwd but keep in mind that AIX user information could be stored externally, so lsuser is more generally correct, as thrig commented.

Answer (score 1):

The `passwd` file is a `:` delimited file.  So the first field is always the username, and so on.

(Side note: `man 5 passwd` describes the fields).

In this case, given a username you want the GECOS field.

This *could* be done with `sed`, but other tools may be better.  `awk` makes it simple:

```
awk -F: '$1 == "Ravi02" { print $5 }' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard `sed` solution would be

```
sed -n '/^Ravi02:/s/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:\([^:]*\):[^:]*:[^:]*$/\1/p'
```

which can be simplified slightly to

```
sed -n 's/^Ravi02:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:\([^:]*\):[^:]*:[^:]*$/\1/p'
```

The key is that you need to be looking at (counting) colons (**`:`**)
and characters other than colon,
rather than counting characters (`.\{21\}`) and letters (`[a-zA-Z]\{50\}`) —
especially since you want to be able
to match characters like comma (`,`) and space in the full name field.

On my system, the following variations also work:

- `sed -n '/^Ravi02:/s/^\([^:]*:\)\{4\}\([^:]*\)\(:[^:]*\)\{2\}$/\2/p'`
- `sed -n 's/^Ravi02:\([^:]*:\)\{3\}\([^:]*\)\(:[^:]*\)\{2\}$/\2/p'`
- `sed -nE '/^Ravi02:/s/^([^:]*:){4}([^:]*)(:[^:]*){2}$/\2/p'`
- `sed -nE 's/^Ravi02:([^:]*:){3}([^:]*)(:[^:]*){2}$/\2/p'`

but I’m not sure whether they will all work on all systems (e.g., AIX).